# Integrate clearcase with Hudson

Tags: hudson, clearcase, hudson-plugins, cleartool

I am trying to integrate clearcase with Hudson, but auto build is not triggering while merge or checkout.

Created dynamic view "sundaa4_Hudson_Test" and gave the config spec which I used in clearcase

[image: Configuration]

When I gave manual build its showing error

[image: Console]

Workspace is not creating in path .hudson\jobs\Hudson_Testing_Sijith\workspace

PLease give some input on this

Comment: I am actually trying to integrate a dynamic view on Base Clearcase with Hudson. My config spec ends with 

    element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch BranchName

I tried to make the MVFS drive to M:\ViewName. Still it didn't detect changes on the branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your config spec ends with a selection rule like:

```
element * /main/LATEST
```

Or it won't select much, which would explain why Hudson doesn't create anything (it doesn't detect any change).

A `cleartool lsview` which returns a line starting with '`*`' means the dynamic view is *already* started: no need to repeat multiple `cleartool startview`.

Make sure your View root does exists: usually, the MVFS drive for dynamic view is `M:\`, not `K:\`.